# How do I make leg joints bend better?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I'm using the metarig for my model, but the legs bend uncomfortably around the crotch, knees, and foot heels. Is there a way to make them bend more natural? Preferably that doesn't involve drivers or shape keys because I don't know how to use them nor I'm good with.[image]

Comment: Hello, to add to B.Pader, maybe share your file so that we can test some solutions

Comment: If you mean by "metarig" Rigify's metarig then please note that this is not meant to be used for animation. You must generate the animation rig from the metarig.

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to rig, you can try to create a "double joints" system to have better deformation for your character's legs.

Here is a good source for creating this kind of behavior :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbQX8C3lrHE&list=PLZpDYt0cyiusytIPAOTPRzsa4GK6LgY3_&index=2

But I would still recommend to use shape keys and drivers. They can help a lot doing specific deformation at very small scales that can correct this kind of behavior automatically.

Here is another useful link on how to do this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zld2-Sq8M2w&list=PLZpDYt0cyiusytIPAOTPRzsa4GK6LgY3_&index=15

Hope this help